# xml schema regex - how to select capital letter followed by all lowercase

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

So I have to following XML elements:

```
<branch>
    <branchName>Emperor</branchName>
</branch>
```

and

```
<branch>
    <branchName>Perception<branchName>
</branch>
```

.. and so on, all of which start with a capital letter and the rest is lowercase. I tried to use Regex to capture this however this is my first time using it an I just throw together the following:

```
"[A-Z](([a-z])*)"
```

When I tried to validate my schema using the [validator](http://www.xpathtester.com/validate) it did not work, I got an error saying:

```
ERROR - cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'Emperor' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[A-Z](([a-z])*)' for type '#AnonType_branchNamebranchbranches'.
ERROR - cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'Emperor' of element 'branchName' is not valid.
ERROR - cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'Perception' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[A-Z](([a-z])*)' for type '#AnonType_branchNamebranchbranches'.
ERROR - cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'Perception' of element 'branchName' is not valid.
```

Essentially I looked at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_facets.asp) version of how to restrict data. After that I looked around for a tutorial for regular expressions but none show how to combine expressions, they just show how you write individual parts.

1) My question is how do I show this using a regular expression? (An uppercase followed by n number of lower cases)

2) could you direct me to a good tutorial that shows from start to end how to  create a regular expression for xml

(An answer to 1 is appreciated but only if 2 is also answered. I do want to learn this for myself)

edit 31/03/2016 @ 01:38: Changed the question in order to make what I was asking more clear.

Comment: Your regular expression is correct: it matches any string that starts with an (English) capital letter where the rest is lower case. If it "doesn't work", then tell us how it fails. Your regex can be simplified to `[A-Z][a-z]*`; the parentheses are redundant but not wrong. If you require at least one lower-case letter after the capital letter, change "*" to "+".

Comment: Downvoting because any question that says something "doesn't work" without saying how it fails deserves a downvote.

Comment: We're reading *however it does not work* but not reading any error message.  We're also reading a verbose regex, but not one that would cause an error.   Finally, we're reading XML without a single root element, but we don't know where your real problem is because all you've not provided an error message.

Comment: @kjhughes The answer I selected seemed to understand what the problem was. Why can't you? I thought it was clear I was asking about the syntax of the regular expression I used. I wasn't asking about anything else, because I wasn't concerned about it. After I fixed the regular expression I then fixed the syntax of the xml and the schema.

Comment: As Michael has told you, your regex is correct.  The answer you chose would not eliminate any error.  (Furthermore, the answer you chose is currently incorrect because it has a leading `^` which it cribbed from another incorrect answer.)   The `maxOccurs="unbounded"` on a root element is an actual error with your XSD.  However, like the multiple XML root elements, which you just fixed, it too could be a mere artifact of your poor question.  Had you posted the ***actual error message***, you could have had a real answer in a fraction of the time it's taking us try to teach you ***[ask]***.

Comment: @kjhughes The regex wasn't correct, if you go to this website https://regex101.com/r/pT7vR9/4 you will see that it is missing out the last character. However if you use this expression here https://regex101.com/r/pT7vR9/3 it captures everything fine. I was nesting something into a group when I shouldn't have been. The problem was the regular expression wasn't capturing what I was wanting it to capture. I asked that in the question.

Comment: @kjhughes. **I'm perfectly aware that maxOccurs="unbounded" is an error** I was not asking about that, it was so simple to solve I didn't bother asking about it. I asked about regular expressions not why my code wasn't validating. I used the validator to check what was wrong and I got a bunch of errors. One of them was the regular expression. I knew how to solve the rest, the regular expression I didn't I googled the answer, found nothing helpful then asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: @kjhughes The reason why there are other syntax errors in the code was I took out the rest which wasn't relevant. All you needed to see was what element I was checking, and the pattern I used. If it pleases you I will take out the rest of the useless stuff.

Comment: [The W3C XML Schema standard defines its own regular expression flavor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html), so your test case links do not prove your point.   In fact, [your regex works fine](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=e62af166-df6e-458f-b03b-d43578d6cb5a-xsdvalidation).   I'm bowing out here.   Good luck.

Comment: James: Yes I can read. I also try to spell people's names correctly. Please don't insult people who are trying to help you. The regular expression in your question was valid, I couldn't see any reason why it should fail, and since you had provided no information about the way in which it failed, I wasn't able to make any progress in solving your question. So I thought it would be helpful to tell you why I wasn't able to help. The answer from @noob, which you accepted, does not address the question of why your code failed.

Comment: @MichaelKay At what point were you trying to help? To me all I got from your comment was you weren't happy with the way I worded the question. Which, btw had two summarised questions bellow so you knew **exactly** what I wanted answered. The answer I selected showed me what was wrong, I was grouping something I shouldn't have and it caused it to not select the correct elements. Feel free the read my 3rd comment up which shows exactly what the problem was. I never realised what "( )" done so I was using it incorrectly. I now know thanks to noob 's answer.

Comment: I studied your question, I discovered certain information, I discovered that other information was missing, and I shared my conclusions. If you don't consider that helpful, you shouldn't be on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) My question is how do I show this using a regular expression? (An uppercase followed by n number of lower cases)

Using regex like this.

**Regex:** `^[A-Z][a-z]+`. If you use `*` instead of `+` it will also match is there are `zero` lower case letters.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pT7vR9/3)**

Answer (score -1):

you can try with with out ^ it will match  aBc also as correct string.

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+
```

Comment: ▲ for pointing that out. I assumed that OP's string will start with capital case.

Comment: Wrong answer. In XSD, regular expressions are implicitly anchored, and the "^" and "$" characters are not used to match the start and end of the string.